# Display same height picture to fill up the width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create the gallery like the way facebook display their album. Photos thumbnails has same height, fill up from left to right with no white gap at the end. How can I do this?

So I tried to fill up the width of window by multiple picture. These picture should line up by row and push down when the window resize (similar to masonry responsive grid but in horizontal). I tried to make they line up in row by set the same height. However, the width is not fully 100% and it just break the line when total width reach the window size.

[image: What I have done]

[image: What I want to do]

```
Check this pen for more details:
https://codepen.io/viet272/pen/ZNPeMN
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please, put the code inside the question, not as a link. Review [writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question) 
to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: I found the solution by using flex https://codepen.io/stenehall/pen/yOYZpZ

Full article here :https://stenehall.se/article/a-very-flexible-full-width-image-grid-using-flex/

Comment: @GibsonTran once these links become dead your question won't be helpful for anybody

Comment: You need to define only the width property of image. If width of image holder is suppose 1000px and you want to place 4 images in a row, then fix the width of image to width: 250px and set height: auto;

Comment: Did you tried giving `margin:0` to `.my-gallery figure` class?